# Axon EventHandler does not receive event

Tags: java, event-bus, axon

I need help with correct configuration of an Axon Application, or my understanding of axon is wrong. I have two aggregates:

- "FileStore", which shall store the information about indexed files
- "DirectoryLister", which sends events for each file it indexes.

The problem I am having, is that "DirectoryLister" sends the event using

```
AggregateLifecycle.apply(new IndexedFileEvent(...));
```

And inside "DirectoryLister" I am able to catch the event in an EventSourcingHandler. But inside the "FileStore" then event handler does not react. I verified that the event is published on the event bus. 
I figured, I need to use the "AnnotationEventListenerAdapter" to somehow make the FileStore listen on the eventbus, but I could not find an example without spring on how this works.

I am using Axon 3.4.3 without Spring and configure the application like this:

```
    Configurer configer = DefaultConfigurer.defaultConfiguration();
    configer.configureEmbeddedEventStore(c -> new InMemoryEventStorageEngine());
    // configure two Aggregates
    configer.configureAggregate(FileStore.class);
    configer.configureAggregate(DirectoryLister.class);

    // how can I register FileStore as an eventListener? Using AnnotationEventListenerAdapter?

    Configuration config = configer.buildConfiguration();

    // verify that event is published on the event bus
    config.eventBus().subscribe(l -> l.forEach( e -> System.out.println(e.toString())));
    config.start();
```

The FileStore class looks like this:

```
public class FileStore {
    @AggregateIdentifier String id; 

    public FileStore() { }

    @CommandHandler public FileStore(CreateFileStoreCommand command) {
        AggregateLifecycle.apply(new FileStoreCreatedEvent(command.getId()));
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler public void on(FileStoreCreatedEvent event) {
        id = event.getId();
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler public void on(IndexedFileEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.getParentPath() + "//" + event.getName() + "  " + event.getSize().toString());
    }
```

The "DirectoryLister" class looks like this:

```
  public class DirectoryLister {
    @AggregateIdentifier String id; 

    protected  DirectoryLister() { }

    @CommandHandler public DirectoryLister(CreateListerCommand cmd) {
        AggregateLifecycle.apply(new CreateListerEvent(cmd.getId()));   
    }

    @CommandHandler public void handleCommand(IndexDirectoryCommand cmd) throws IOException {
         FileVisitor<Path> fv = new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
              @Override
              public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                // this is where the event is sent!
                AggregateLifecycle.apply(new IndexedFileEvent(file.getFileName().toString(),file.getParent().toString(), attrs.size())); 
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
              }
            };

          Files.walkFileTree(cmd.getPath(), fv);
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler public void on (CreateListerEvent event) { id = event.getId(); }

    // This handler is invoked. 
    @EventSourcingHandler public void on(IndexedFileEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.getParentPath() + "//" + event.getName() + "  " + event.getSize().toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow correctly, you are trying to handle events, which have been published from Aggregate `DirectoryLister`, in Aggregate `FileStore`, correct?

However, this assumption is inherently impossible.
The Aggregate you are describing is essentially the Command Model in a CQRS set up.
As such, it *handles commands* from the outside world, and then decides whether the given command/operation can be performed at that stage.
As a result of deducing whether a command can be handled, an event is published notifying "something has happened".

The Command Model is however **not** intended to handle events directly. 
The only time it handles events, is to "source itself from the change which it has published".
This is why an event handler in an aggregate is not an `@EventHandler` in Axon, but an `@EventSourcingHandler`, as it can **only** handle the events from its own source.

The Reference Guide also states that handling events from other Aggregates within a given Aggregate is not possible (which you can find [here](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/implementing-domain-logic/command-handling/aggregate#applying-events-from-event-sourcing-handlers)).

So, simply put, what you're expecting is not possible Mathias.
You will need to place an Event Handling Component in between which reacts on the given event from the `DirectoryLister` and translates that to a command you want to perform on the `FileStore`.